# How to launch method when window got focus again in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

My app is multi-window, here is quickly how it works:

In main window  I have a list of items, when I click on one, it opens another window where I can modify it. When I close that window, I want main window to refresh its content. I've tried many event handlers including GotFocus() but it doesn't want to launch my method to refresh the list. Any advise?

Comment: Why can't you use Delegates - events  with notifier in child form and listener in main window?

Comment: Did you tried to handle `Activated` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something to happen when the other window is closed, you can subscribe to its closed event. This will fire when the windows is closed.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wnd = new Window1();
        wnd.Closed += wnd_Closed;
        wnd.Show();
    }

    void wnd_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Closed");
    }
```